# Using root to clear the status bar notifications

Tags: android

I am currently working on an app using an **accessibility service** to handle notifications. What is particularly annoying is **there is no way for third party apps to clear the status bar notifications**, other than launching the intent linked to the notification (and launch the app).

I have searched for a long time for a way to **use root to dismiss a notification** or clear the complete list, but I have failed.

I think I remember an app I saw that cleared the status bar by quickly opening the status bar and clicking the clear button programmatically, but I can't find it anymore, and I think it was on Android 2.2.

I was wondering if there was a way to interact with the status bar notifications using some kind of **database** or with a simple **SU** call.

Comment: As far as I know, the status bar notification is used also by applications, which require root rights. The reason for it is that if they're running some background processes, the Android itslef can not stop of kill the process/or the application, because of that Status Bar notification. You would like to clear the status bar, which is occupied by some other applications - right?

Comment: @g00dy In a nutshell, I want to dismissis any non-ongoing notification (email, SMS etc, but not voicemail, USB debugging) regardless of whether its from my app or not. I know this can't be done through the public SDK. Just wondering if anyone managed it with Root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE** - See working solution below

All this stuff gets handled by the NotificationManagerService (see here: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/NotificationManagerService.java). I think in particular you'd be interested in the void cancelAll(int userId) method. When you press clear on the status screen that's the method that  actually gets invoked (with ActivityManager.getCurrentUser() as parameter).

You could try to obtain an instance of it by calling NotificationManager.getService via reflection (see hidden getService() method in NotificationManager http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/NotificationManager.java) and then try to somehow invoke cancelAll on the returned service (e.g. via reflection again).

**UPDATE**

I found an easier way to clear notifications via the statusbar service. The following code should work:

```
IBinder b = (IBinder) Class.forName("android.os.ServiceManager").getMethod("getService", new Class[] {
    String.class
}).invoke(null, new Object[] {
    "statusbar"
});

Object iFace = Class.forName("com.android.internal.statusbar.IStatusBarService$Stub").getDeclaredMethod("asInterface", new Class[] {
    IBinder.class
}).invoke(null, new Object[] {
    b
});

iFace.getClass().getMethod("onClearAllNotifications", new Class[0]).invoke(iFace, (Object[]) null);
```

This will throw a SecurityException if you are not running as root but successfully clears notifications if you have root permissions

Answer (score 4):

You can clear all the notifications by calling

```
service call notification 1
```

in the shell with root permission