# How to Clear other apps Notification from status bar progmatically in rooted device

Tags: android

I am using rooted device and i want to clear the other apps notification programatically from the status bar.
I tried this :

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.cancelAll();
```

but this is not working in my tablet

Comment: evnen i try to solve it though this but it's not working 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14953342/using-root-to-clear-the-status-bar-notifications

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233518/6549598

Comment: if i don't want to store it then is there any other way to clear notification ?

Comment: No, because notifications are canceled by the unique id assigned to them at the creation time and you need to get that id in order to cancel them.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since API 18, this method (`notificationManager.cancellAll()`) no longer works as expected, but I'm not sure about it. It looks like you need to create listener, which will listen when notifications are created and cancelled, store their objects somewhere and then you'll be able to remove objects and cancel notifications.

Check out this answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31233518/1150795.

Comment: is there any other way to clear it without storing all id's

Comment: Maybe there is, but I don't know it. If `manager.cancellAll()` doesn't work (IMO it should if it's in the API and is not deprecated), I'd go with collecting all notification ids and cancelling each notification individually in the loop.